# Finding physical gamejams

Tags: game-industry

I'm interested in participating in some gamejams and was hoping to be able to attend one in person. Is there a way I could search for gamejams in the general Dallas area?

Comment: Presumably you started by [searching for "Dallas game jam" in your favourite search engine](https://www.google.com/search?q=dallas+game-jam), right? This turns up a bunch of promising results for me — did you find the results unsatisfactory in any way?

Comment: I did try that and I ended up finding a bunch of past jams and stuff for non-jam related events. I was hoping for a strategy or way of finding something coming up.